Is it possible to set Russian phonetic layout to Logitech K480 keyboard?
Is it possible to set the Russian phonetic layout to the Logitech K480 keyboard?
I bought this keyboard, Logitech K480:
https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B00MUTWLW4
I can't figure out how I can change the keyboard layout when I work with my Android Samsung tablet. On Windows, there is a setting that allows to change the keyboard layout (mapping between Russian and English letters).
Russian phonetic layout is a mapping of English letters to visually similar Russian letters.
But is it possible to do it with this keyboard when using an Android tablet?
Thanks!

Related/possible dupe: There is no Armenian in Logitech K480 physical keyboard language list (while the question asked for a specific answer, the answer seems for a general case). Also, the answerer seems to be experienced with external keyboard mapping, browsing his other answers might help.
